# Parse output of spawned node.js child process line by line

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I have a PhantomJS/CasperJS script which I'm running from within a node.js script using `process.spawn()`. Since CasperJS doesn't support `require()`ing modules, I'm trying to print commands from CasperJS to `stdout` and then read them in from my node.js script using `spawn.stdout.on('data', function(data) {});` in order to do things like add objects to redis/mongoose (convoluted, yes, but seems more straightforward than setting up a web service for this...) The CasperJS script executes a series of commands and creates, say, 20 screenshots which need to be added to my database.

However, I can't figure out how to break the `data` variable (a `Buffer`?) into lines... I've tried converting it to a string and then doing a replace, I've tried doing `spawn.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');` but nothing seems to work...

Here is what I have right now

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var bin = "casperjs"
//googlelinks.js is the example given at http://casperjs.org/#quickstart
var args = ['scripts/googlelinks.js'];
var cspr = spawn(bin, args);

//cspr.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
cspr.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    var buff = new Buffer(data);
    console.log("foo: " + buff.toString('utf8'));
});

cspr.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    data += '';
    console.log(data.replace("\n", "\nstderr: "));
});

cspr.on('exit', function (code) {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
    process.exit(code);
});
```

https://gist.github.com/2131204

Comment: Is this the best approach? It seems like the `stdout.on('data')` event fires depending upon buffer size, not necessarily new lines. Is this true?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```javascript
cspr.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
cspr.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
  var str = data.toString(), lines = str.split(/(\r?\n)/g);
  for (var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
    // Process the line, noting it might be incomplete.
  }
});
```

Note that the "data" event might not necessarily break evenly between lines of output, so a single line might span multiple data events.

Comment: Weird, I'm on OSX - I thought "\r\n" was Windows. But it seems to work! (after adding a handful of missing parentheses :p)

Comment: @JesseFulton: the `\r` is optional from the regex special character `?` so this code should work on both UNIX and Windows; it's making the regular expression global (`.../g`) that was probably critical here.  The call to "replace" in your sample code used a plain string which gets converted into a non-global regex, so you probably got just two lines instead of all of them.

Comment: Ah, yea you're right. String.replace(String, String) isn't global - you need to use a regex as the first param and add the 'g' switch.

Comment: @mehaase: which comment?

Comment: While this solution sometimes works, I'd like to see the one which always works.

Answer (score 15):

I found a nicer way to do this with just pure node, which seems to work well:

```js
const childProcess = require('child_process');
const readline = require('readline');

const cspr = childProcess.spawn(bin, args);

const rl = readline.createInterface({ input: cspr.stdout });
rl.on('line', line => /* handle line here */)
```

This can also be conveniently done in `async` form rather than callback form with:

```js
;(async function() {
for await (const line of rl) {
  /* handle line here */
}
})()
```

Comment: Beautiful solution, thank you @nyctef !!

Comment: I also provided a minimal example with a sleeping counter at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14332721/node-js-spawn-child-process-and-get-terminal-output-live/77423073#77423073

Answer (score 13):

I've actually written a Node library for exactly this purpose, it's called stream-splitter and you can find it on Github: [samcday/stream-splitter](http://github.com/samcday/stream-splitter).

The library provides a special `Stream` you can pipe your casper stdout into, along with a delimiter (in your case, \n), and it will emit neat `token` events, one for each line it has split out from the input `Stream`. The internal implementation for this is very simple, and delegates most of the magic to [substack/node-buffers](https://github.com/substack/node-buffers) which means there's no unnecessary `Buffer` allocations/copies.

Comment: This library is a great time saver in this particular case. Thanks!

Comment: +1 this just worked for me. hassles all gone. Thanks!

Comment: Works with child_process: var splitter = proc.stdout.pipe(StreamSplitter('\n')); splitter.on('token', (token) => { console.log(token) }; // Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Adding to maerics' answer, which does not deal properly with cases where only part of a line is fed in a data dump (theirs will give you the first part and the second part of the line individually, as two separate lines.)

```
var _breakOffFirstLine = /\r?\n/
function filterStdoutDataDumpsToTextLines(callback){ //returns a function that takes chunks of stdin data, aggregates it, and passes lines one by one through to callback, all as soon as it gets them.
    var acc = ''
    return function(data){
        var splitted = data.toString().split(_breakOffFirstLine)
        var inTactLines = splitted.slice(0, splitted.length-1)
        var inTactLines[0] = acc+inTactLines[0] //if there was a partial, unended line in the previous dump, it is completed by the first section.
        acc = splitted[splitted.length-1] //if there is a partial, unended line in this dump, store it to be completed by the next (we assume there will be a terminating newline at some point. This is, generally, a safe assumption.)
        for(var i=0; i<inTactLines.length; ++i){
            callback(inTactLines[i])
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
process.stdout.on('data', filterStdoutDataDumpsToTextLines(function(line){
    //each time this inner function is called, you will be getting a single, complete line of the stdout ^^
}) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a try. It will ignore any empty lines or empty new line breaks.

```
cspr.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    data = data.toString().split(/(\r?\n)/g);
    data.forEach((item, index) => {
        if (data[index] !== '\n' && data[index] !== '') {
            console.log(data[index]);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Old stuff but still useful...

I have made a custom stream Transform subclass for this purpose.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59400367/4861714

Answer (score 0):

@nyctef's answer uses an official nodejs package.

Here is a link to the documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html

> The node:readline module provides an interface for reading data from a Readable stream (such as process.stdin) one line at a time.

My personal use-case is parsing json output from the "docker watch" command created in a spawned child_process.

```
  const dockerWatchProcess = spawn(...)
  ...
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: dockerWatchProcess.stdout,
    output: null,
  });

  rl.on('line', (log: string) => {
    console.log('dockerWatchProcess event::', log);
    // code to process a change to a docker event
    ...
  });
```