# How pass system parameters for phantomjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20478278/1251549) is en example about running phantomjs and passing parameters to it. But how to pass `--disk-cache=true` to it? Does this correct version?

```
var childArgs = [
  path.join(__dirname, 'phantomjs-script.js'),
  'argumentForJsScript',
  '--disk-cache=true',
  '--disk-cache-path=C:\somepath'
]
```

I am tryinh to run this and everythings seems to work, but folder `C:\somepath` don't contain any files. So it seems that `disk-cache` parameters are not recognized by `phamtomjs` engine and just passed to the js script. Are they?

Answer (score 0):

Any parameters that are meant for PhantomJS should be passed **before** a script.

```
var childArgs = [
  '--disk-cache=true',
  '--disk-cache-path=C:\somepath',
  '--cookies-file=C:\somepath\cookies.txt',
  path.join(__dirname, 'phantomjs-script.js'),
  'argumentForJsScript'
]
```