# Async function not awaiting the result of child process in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, exec

Javascript/Node beginner here.

I've consulted several posts ([Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47629756/how-can-i-get-the-returned-value-from-the-child-process-exec-in-javascript), [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443597/node-js-execute-system-command-synchronously)) but I am getting an error on my following Node.js code:

```js
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;

async function execute(){
  let result = await sh();
  console.log("RESULT: " + result);
}

async function sh(){
  execFile('./demo-files/demo.sh', ['1st', '2nd', '3rd'], 
  function(err, data){
    let returnValue;
    if(err){
      returnValue = "ERROR:\n" + err;
    }
    else {
      returnValue = data.toString();
    }
    console.log("return value in fxn: " + returnValue);
    return returnValue;
  });
}

execute();
```

The console output:

```sh
RESULT: undefined
return value in fxn: 2nd
```

Why does my `await` not wait for the result of `sh()`? I expected it to return the value "2nd".

(The bash script is inconsequential; it's just `echo $2`)

Comment: you don't await inside `sh` ... what do you expect to wait for? you don't even return anything from that function either

Comment: First, `await` only does something useful when you await a promise.  Second, `sh()` doesn't return a promise so third, the await has no effect at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `await` your function, but that function is not really `async`. When a function has `async` keyword before it, what it actually does is wrap the whole function to [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instance. But if you won't handle what is inside this function correctly, it won't work.

In your case, you need return [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instance manually. It accepts callback with `resolve` & `reject` arguments. And you can call `resolve` to resolve the promise:

```js
function sh() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        execFile('./demo-files/demo.sh', ['1st', '2nd', '3rd'],
            function (err, data) {
                let returnValue;
                if (err) {
                    returnValue = "ERROR:\n" + err;
                }
                else {
                    returnValue = data.toString();
                }
                console.log("return value in fxn: " + returnValue);
                resolve(returnValue);
            })
    })
}
```

Comment: in this case you wouldn't use `async` since you have no need to use `await` inside `sh`

Comment: Good answer. @Bravo is correct though, please remove the unused (confusing) `async` keyword.

Comment: `async` isn't used to say "hey, this function does something asynchronous" - it's used to say "I want to use `await` on a Promise inside this function to make the code simpler

Comment: Sure, removed it, it's not necessary, especially if you don't understand what it dooes. I used it because of habit. The code style I use recommends marking all async functions  (including function which returns promise) with `aync` keyword, I even have eslint rule for that in all projects.

Comment: @KiraLT - I'd wager you don't fully understand what it does if you use it in functions that are asynchronous, regardless if they use promises or not

Comment: It is discussable if it's actually useful, you can find more on https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/promise-function-async.md

Answer (score 0):

Since execFile doesn't return a Promise, and async/await is syntax sugar for working with promises, your code can never "wait" for the execFile to run

An alternative is to use node.js "promisify"

```
const util = require('util');
const execFile = util.promisify(require('child_process').execFile);
```

then your sh function can be

```
const util = require('util');
const execFile = util.promisify(require('child_process').execFile);

async function execute(){
  let result = await sh();
  console.log("RESULT: " + result);
}

function sh(){
  return execFile('./demo-files/demo.sh', ['1st', '2nd', '3rd'])
  .then(data => data.toString())
  .catch(err => "ERROR:\n" + err);
}
```

Or, using async/await for `function sh`

```
const util = require('util');
const execFile = util.promisify(require('child_process').execFile);

async function execute(){
  let result = await sh();
  console.log("RESULT: " + result);
}

async function sh(){
  try {
    const data = await execFile('./demo-files/demo.sh', ['1st', '2nd', '3rd']);
    return data.toString();
  } catch (err) {
    return "ERROR:\n" + err;
  }
}
```