# Child_process handling a STDOUT stream with carriage return (\r)

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, rsync, child-process

I'm writing a simple(ish) application that allows an internal system at work to request a copy process (using rsync) from a remote server to another remote server instigated using a REST call.

I'm already familiar enough with the express framework, and have just started experimenting with the child_process library, and stumbled upon a small problem.

I am successfully starting rsync processes using node's `childProcess.spawn()`, my issue is that rsync outputs its progress line-buffered with a carriage return (\r) instead of an newline (\n). As a result the STDOUT event, `process.stdout.on('data', {})` is only called once before saying it's setting up the transfer, and then after the copy has finished, as STDOUT data isn't flushed on a carriage return, as the progress updates, only a newline, when the job finishes.

There is a switch in the latest version of rsync (3.1.0) to change the output buffer endings to \n instead of \r but unfortunately, the company I work at will not be adopting this version for a long time.

I'm spawning and reading the child_process in the usual way....

```
var doCopy = function (onFinish) {
    var process = childProcess.spawn('ssh', [
        source.user + "@" + source.host,
        "rsync",
        "-avz",
        "--progress",
        source.path + source.file,
        "-e ssh",
        dest.user + "@" + dest.host + ":" + dest.path
    ]);

    process.on('error', function (error) {
        console.log("ERR: " + error.code);
    })

    process.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log("OUT: " + data);
    });

    process.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log("ERR: " + data);
    });

    process.on('close', function (code) {
        console.log("FIN: " + code);
        if(onFinish){
            onFinish(code);
        }
    });
}
```

..and the console output is....

```
OUT: building file list ... 
OUT: 
1 file to consider

OUT: test4.mp4

         32,768   0%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00  
    169,738,240  32%  161.84MB/s    0:00:02  
    338,165,760  64%  161.32MB/s    0:00:01  
    504,692,736  96%  160.53MB/s    0:00:00  
    524,288,000 100%  160.35MB/s    0:00:03 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)

OUT: 
sent 509,959 bytes  received 46 bytes  113,334.44 bytes/sec
total size is 524,288,000  speedup is 1,028.01

FIN: 0
```

So you can see that the stdout.on('data,) is only called when rsync outputs a new line (where there is an 'OUT:').

My question is, can I change this? Maybe put the stream through a transform to flush when a \r occurs? Then I can regex the line and offer a progress update back again.

Failing this, I suppose my only other option would be to spawn another process to monitor the growing file?

Any help/advise is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found [this](https://github.com/samcday/node-stream-splitter) very good module that does exactly what I was trying to achieve. Allows me to delimit the stdout buffer by any character (in my case '\r') and trigger a new stdout event to handle the data. Like....

```
var splitter = process.stdout.pipe(StreamSplitter("\r"));

splitter.on('token', function (data) {
    console.log("OUT: " + data);
});

splitter.on('done', function (data) {
    console.log("DONE: " + data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made a custom stream Transform subclass for this purpose. The pro is that you can also tag your lines with your child process favorite name and it handles given `\r` the right way.

Feel free to try my implementation:
(in typescript but you could easily remove all type stuff)

```js
import { ChildProcessWithoutNullStreams } from "child_process";
import { Transform } from "stream";

export default class LineTagTransform extends Transform {
  lastLineData = '';
  tag = '';

  constructor(tag?: string) {
    super({ objectMode: true });

    this.tag = tag || '';
    if (tag && !tag.endsWith(' ')) this.tag += ' ';
  }

  _transform(chunk: Buffer | string | any, encoding: string, callback: Function) {
    let data: string = chunk.toString().replace(/\r(?!\n)/, '\n\r');
    if (this.lastLineData) data = this.lastLineData + data;

    let lines = data.split(/\r?\n/);
    this.lastLineData = lines.splice(lines.length - 1, 1)[0];

    for (const line of lines) {
      if (line.startsWith('\r')) {
        this.push(`\r${this.tag}${line.substring(1)}`);
      } else {
        this.push(`\n${this.tag}${line}`)
      }
    }
    callback();
  }

  _flush(callback: Function) {
    if (this.lastLineData) {
      if (this.lastLineData.startsWith('\r')) {
        this.push(`\r${this.tag}${this.lastLineData.substring(1)}`);
      } else {
        this.push(`\n${this.tag}${this.lastLineData}`)
      }
    }
    this.lastLineData = '';
    callback();
  }

  static wrapStreams(child: ChildProcessWithoutNullStreams, tag?: string, stdout: NodeJS.WriteStream = process.stdout, stderr: NodeJS.WriteStream = process.stderr) {
    child.stdout.pipe(new LineTagTransform(tag)).pipe(stdout);
    child.stderr.pipe(new LineTagTransform(tag)).pipe(stderr);
  }
}
```

Then the easiest way to use it:

```js
const child = spawn('./DownloadUnicorn.exe', options);
LineTagTransform.wrapStreams(child, '[unicorn]');
```

Outputs:

```
[unicorn] Start DownloadUnicorn!
[unicorn] Downloading [=====-----] 50%
...
```

With download bar animation on a single line! \o/

HTH! ;)