# How to get data from python script at Node.js?

Tags: python, node.js, child-process, spawn

I'm trying to get data from python script at Node.js server.
I need to launch this python script with superuser privileges.

```
child.execFile('sudo python /home/pi/node.js_scripts/app/request.py', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
if (err) throw err;
if (stderr) throw err;
console.log(stdout); });
```

But i get this error:

```
Error: spawn sudo python /home/pi/node.js_scripts/app/request.py ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1046:32)
    at child_process.js:1137:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [`execFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback) takes a path to a file. This file needs to be executable. In your case, you're trying to execute a command. Try [`child.exec()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) instead, or create a small executable shell script that runs this command.

Also, giving your node.js server sudo permissions is not wise. I don't have any good advice on how to solve that problem though. Maybe look into [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid). It really depends on your use-case (and should be a separate question).

Comment: Thanks, i've tried child.exec() but it can return only 200K max because of buffer capacity. Is it possible to spawn process with sudo?

I agree with you about sudo permissions but actually i don't know better way to avoid it.

Comment: I think you'll have the same problem with execFile? You can use the `maxBuffer` option with `exec`, but maybe you should read from the child so that your buffer is not filled up. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9781295/98057) for example.

Comment: You could also [redirect output to a file](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdio),